# php mailform with JAvascript validation

Tags: java, php, html

I'm having a problem with my one page contact form.

When i click the submit button, i run a javascript check to see if the fields are filled.

The check works fine but i don't have any clue why the PHP isn't responing.

i can't use another php page to do the processing because i want to use the same contact page for other contact purposes.

So this is the sequence i want to get:

```
 1. Form gets filled in
 2. On click of the submit butten, javascript checks the fields.
 3. If okay, javascript submits the form
 4. if mail has been sent, the page is reloaded to  contact.php?MailStatus=Success
 5. if not (it will run a javascript giving en errormessage telling the user to retry without the fields being cleared.
```

contact.php (code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Mijn Dier En Ik</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="author" content="www.csl-tech.be" />
    <meta name="description" content="Op zoek naar dierenhotels, artsen, winkels,... Dan is Mijn Huisdier en Ik de website die je zoekt. Neem een kijkje!" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSLCSS.css">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container csl-main">
        <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
                <form id="MailForm" method="post">
                    <div id="Message"></div>

                    <div id="FormFields">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fname">Voornaam</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Uw voornaam...">
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="lname">Achternaam</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Uw achternaam...">
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Uw e-mail...">
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="country">Land</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country">
                            <option value="Belgie">België</option>
                            <option value="Nederland">Nederland</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subject">Onderwerp</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject">
                            <option value="Vragen">Vragen over Mijn Dier en Ik</option>
                            <option value="Suggesties">Suggesties voor de website</option>
                            <option value="Reservatie of Contact">Vragen over het reservatie- en/of contactsysteem</option>
                            <option value="Foto inzending">Foto inzenden</option>
                            <option value="Aanpassing gegevens">Aanpassing gegevens</option>
                            <option value="Andere">Andere</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message">Uw bericht</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Typ hier uw bericht..." style="height:200px"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <br />

                    <input id="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Versturen" onclick="CheckMailEntry()">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<?php
    if ($_GET['MailStatus'] == 'Success') {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">MailSuccess()</script>';
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        header('Location: contact.php?MailStatus=Success');
        echo 'ok';
    }
?>


</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
function CheckMailEntry() {

    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "";
    if (document.getElementById("fname").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Fout:</strong> Voer uw voornaam in.</div>";
    } else if (document.getElementById("lname").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Fout:</strong> Voer uw achternaam in.</div>";
    } else if (document.getElementById("email").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Fout:</strong> Voer uw email in.</div>";
    } else if (document.getElementById("message").value == "") {
        document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Fout:</strong> Gelieve een bericht te typen.</div>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("submit").submit();
    };

};



function MailSuccess() {
    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Succes:</strong> Wij hebben uw mail ontvangen en zullen deze zo snel mogelijk beantwoorden.</div>";
    document.getElementById("FormFields").innerHTML = "";
};
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @Rainmx93 like i said,,  PHP isn't responding  so the  echo 'ok';   doesn't come up

Comment: ok doesn't come up because you don't have element with name submit

Comment: @Rainmx93  is the POST listening to name of ID,,    because i have an element that has that ID

Comment: No, only to name attribute

Comment: from documentation: `Each input field must have a name attribute to be submitted.

If the name attribute is omitted, the data of that input field will not be sent at all.`

Comment: i changed ID to Name     also in javascript.  Still no PHP action here

Comment: @Rainmx93 i gave every element a name  but still nothing happens...